# Generate random matrix with specific rank and cardinality

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to generate a rectangular matrix `A`, with entries in the closed interval `[0,1]`, which satisfies the following properties:

```
(1) size(A) = (200,2000)
(2) rank(A) = 50
(3) nnz(A) = 100000
```

It will be best if the non-zero elements in `A` will decay exponentially, or at least polynomially (I want significantly more small values than large). 
Obviously (I think...), normalizing to `[0,1]` in the end is not the major issue here.

Things I tried that didn't work:

1. First generating a random matrix with `A=abs(randn(200,2000))` and thresholding

   ```
   th = prctile(A(:),(1-(100000/(200*2000)))*100);
   A = A.*(A>th);
   ```

   Now that property `(3)` is satisfied, I lowered the rank

   ```
   [U,S,V] = svd(A);
   for i=51:200 S(i,i)=0; end
   A = U*S/V;
   ```

   But this matrix has almost full cardinality (I lost propery `(3)`).
2. First generating a matrix with the specified rank with `A=rand(200,50)*rand(50,2000)`. Now that condition `(2)` is satisfied, I threshoded like before. Only now I lost property `(2)` as the matrix has almost full rank.

So... Is there a way to make sure both properties `(2)` and `(3)` are satisfied simultaneously?

P.S. I would like the non-zero entries in the matrix to be distributed in some random/non-structural manner (just making 50 non-zero columns or rows is not my aim...).

Comment: I'm not sure how "random" you can go with the pattern of non zeros. If you have 200 rows with rank 50 you basically have 50 different patterns repeating approximately 4 times each.

Comment: OK it's an interesting comment... I can generate 50 random rows `r_i` with `~500` non zero entries, and for each row of the matrix pick `i` in random. It's not what I'm aiming for, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This satisfies all conditions, with very high probability:

```
A = zeros(200,2000);
A(:,1:500) = repmat(rand(200,50),1,10);
```

You could then then suffle the nonzero columns if desired:

```
A = A(:,randperm(size(A,2)));
```

The matrix has a vertical structure: in 500 colums all elements are nonzero, whereas in the remaining 1500 columns all elements are zero. (Not sure if that's acceptable for your purpose).

Comment: Sorry but this is not my goal... Edited the question in response.

Answer (score 0):

Trivial approach:

```
>> A= rand(200,50);
>> B= zeros(200,1950);
>> A = [A B];
>> A = A(:,randperm(size(A,2)));
>> rank(A)

ans =

    50

>> nnz(A)

ans =

       10000
```

Comment: Not what I meant... I want the non-zero values of the matrix to be distributed randomly as well (or at least with a pattern that is not as simplified as suggested above).